# How to configure docusign demo to live after promoting integration key

Tags: docusignapi

I used embedded signing and after successfully running on demo, promoted integration key and passed review.
What changes I need to in my code? Where I need to put promoted integration key? I know live have no token key integration like demo which is for 8 hours only.

I changed https://demo.docusign.net/restapi to https://www.docusign.net/restapi

```
$dsConfig = array(
        'ds_client_id' => isset($session->data['user_id']) ? $session->data['user_id'] : "1",
        'ds_client_secret' => 'eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'signer_email' => $customer->isLogged() ? $customer->getEmail() : 'user@example.com',
        'signer_name' => $customer->isLogged() ? $customer->getFirstName() . ' ' . $customer->getLastName() : 'John Doe',
        'app_url' => HTTPS_SERVER . 'public/agreement-accept.html',
        'authorization_server' => 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi',
        'session_secret' => isset($session->data['token']) ? $session->data['token'] : md5(time()),
        'allow_silent_authentication' => true,
        'accountId' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'templateId' => 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx'
    );
$config = new Configuration();
$config->setHost($dsConfig['authorization_server']);
$config->addDefaultHeader(
        "Authorization",
        "Bearer " . $dsConfig['ds_client_secret']
    );
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

`https://docusign.net/restapi` is not a valid API endpoint.

In order to make API calls using your integration key, you'll need to implement one of the Authentication Workflows as documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/

Once you have a valid token, you'll need to make a User Info call to determine the base URI for your account: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints

Comment: Yes, I follow the authentication guides(Authentication code grant) and trying to implementing the concept of refresh token, Actually it says token is for 8 hours and refresh token is valid for 30 days, so that means we need to write a code for refreshing token every 29 days 23 hours?

Comment: The Access Token lasts for eight hours, after that you will need to use the Refresh Token to generate a new Access Token. 
Your application needs to be able to catch the consent_required error (or other failures in using the Refresh Token) and direct the user to grant a new instance of application consent if the Refresh Token is invalid.

Comment: I need a api sdk code to get refresh token, I already get access token by  Authorization Code. I have refresh token in that array too but how to get refresh token in every 29 days and 12 hours through API sdk code in php file? 
I have already know 

POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
Authorization: Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN.....

But how to implement in php coding?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating a generateRefreshToken() function in ApiClient Class:-

```
public function generateRefreshToken($client_id = null, $client_secret = null, $refresh_token = null)
{
    if (!$client_id) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $client_id when calling generateAccessToken');
    }
    if (!$client_secret || !$refresh_token) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $client_secret when calling generateAccessToken');
    }
    if (!$refresh_token) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $refresh_token when calling generateAccessToken');
    }

    $resourcePath = "/oauth/token";
    $queryParams = array();
    $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}"));
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization" => $integrator_and_secret_key,
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    );
    $postData = array(
        "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token" => $refresh_token
    );
    list($response, $statusCode, $httpHeader) = $this->callApi($resourcePath, self::$POST, $queryParams, $postData, $headers, null, null, true);
    if(isset($response->access_token))
        $this->config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "{$response->token_type} {$response->access_token}");
    return array($this->getSerializer()->deserialize($response, '\DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\OAuthToken', $httpHeader), $statusCode, $httpHeader);
}

protected static function requestNewToken($refresh_token) {
   $config = new Configuration();
   $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
   $token = $apiClient->generateRefreshToken('clientid', 'secret_key', $refresh_token); 
   return array($token[0]['access_token'],$token[0]['refresh_token'],time() + 86400 * 27);
}


protected static function getToken() {
    $tokenFile = __DIR__ . '/token.json';
    $access_token = null;
    if (file_exists($tokenFile)) {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenFile), true);
        $access_token = $data['access_token']; // todo consider field names
        $refresh_token = $data['refresh_token']; // todo consider field names
        $expires_in = $data['expires_in']; // todo consider field names
        if ($expires_in <= time()) {
            $access_token = null;
        }
    }
    if (!$access_token) {
        list($access_token,$refresh_newtoken,$expires_in) = self::requestNewToken($refresh_token);
        if (!$access_token || !$refresh_newtoken || !$expires_in) {
            throw new Exception('Could not request new token.');
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenFile, json_encode(array(
            'access_token' => $access_token, 
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_newtoken, 
            'expires_in' => $expires_in 
        )));
    }
    return $access_token;
}
```

Also https://www.docusign.net/restapi is a valid API endpoint for production.It works for me. https:// and www should be there...

```
$dsConfig = array(
        'ds_client_id' => isset($session->data['user_id']) ? $session->data['user_id'] : "1",
        // The app's DocuSign integration key's secret
        'ds_client_secret' => $token,
        'signer_email' => $customer->isLogged() ? $customer->getEmail() : 'user@example.com',
        'signer_name' => $customer->isLogged() ? $customer->getFirstName() . ' ' . $customer->getLastName() : 'John Doe',
        // return url
        'app_url' => HTTPS_SERVER . 'public/agreement-accept.html',
        'authorization_server' => 'https://www.docusign.net/restapi',
        'session_secret' => isset($session->data['token']) ? $session->data['token'] : md5(time()),
        'allow_silent_authentication' => true,
        'accountId' => 'xxx',
        'templateId' => 'xxxx'
    );
```

Comment: Also https://www.docusign.net/restapi is a valid API endpoint for production.It works for me @Drew. https:// and www should be there...